# Apache Ignite - how to run Hello World example without any IDE (Eclipse, InteliJ)

Tags: java, ignite

From example here:
https://ggfabric.blogspot.com/2015/12/apache-ignite-hello-world-example.html?showComment=1498501033189

I could start Apache Ignite on my laptop but mvn did not work for me (maybe is outdated version or example).

Is there a very simple example of whole POM file (with version 2.0.0) and simple HelloWorld.java example that can work from command line (via mvn compile) without any IDE (Eclipse, InteliJ etc.). Just want to quickly try Ignite without any additional overheads..

Answer (score 1):

Binary package contains `examples` folder which is a standalone Maven project. You can use it to build and run examples.

Comment: Folder 'apache-ignite-fabric-2.0.0-bin/examples' has these folders and files inside:
`src/
rest/
redis/
memcached/
config/
README.txt
pom.xml`
Can you please give example of one mvn build command with execution after build?

Comment: This is a standard Maven project structure, please refer to Maven documentation for more details. To run a program you can use exec plugin (as one of the options): http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/